# I have a billing account, but I can't route on google directions. I get the message "REQUEST_DENIED"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I have a billing account, but I can't route on google directions. I get the following error message:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: Are you using an API key in your Directions API requests? Is it correctly restricted? Do you have the Directions API enabled on your project? Please double check these and let us know if the issue persists. For guidance also check out Google's guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro